# Create a rainbow chase using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a rainbow cycle/chase effect on 9 pixels.

i need to prepare a json statement that updates all 9 pixels at once

So far i've been able to make all 9 pixels change colors, but not in a chase pattern

here is my code:

```
  var colors = [
"248,12,18",
"238,17,0",    
"255,51,17",    
"255,68,34",
"255,102,68",
"255,153,51",   
"254,174,45",
"204,187,51",
"208,195,16",   
"170,204,34",
"105,208,37",
"34,204,170",   
"18,189,185",
"17,170,187",
"68,68,221",    
"51,17,187",
"59,12,189",
"68,34,153"
]
var i = 0
function f(array) {
 var howManyTimes = array.length;
 json = 'http://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxx?
  hash='+globalHash+'&colours={"1": ['+array[i]+'], "0": 
  ['+array[i]+'], "3": ['+array[i]+'], "2": ['+array[i]+'], "5": 
  ['+array[i]+'], "4": ['+array[i]+'], "7": ['+array[i]+'], "6": 
  ['+array[i]+'], "9": ['+array[i]+'], "8": ['+array[i]+']}'
sendColorChange(json);
i++;
if (i == howManyTimes) { i = 0}
if( i < howManyTimes ){
    setTimeout(function(){f(array)}, 1000);
 }
}
```

so what i need is for the variable json to change every iteration, but instead of changing every pixel to the same color each iteration, i would like it to chase forward, nice little assci art here as an example:

```
[]=pixel  
r=red  
g=green  
b=blue  
w=white  
however, the colors that i want to use are rgb values in the colors array  
iteration 1:  
[r][][][][][][][][][]  
iteration 2:  
[g][r][][][][][][][][]  
iteration 3:  
[b][g][r][][][][][][][]  
iteration 4:  
[w][b][g][r][][][][][][]  
and so on
```

i hope that clears it up a little

Comment: What is a rainbow chase?

Comment: Are you aware that you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert an object or array to JSON? Also, do you really need to change it to JSON? Are you sending that data out to a server somewhere? What does `sendColorChange` do?

Comment: @lilezek here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ8jwDwdMHI

Comment: @MikeC yes its sending the data to e server, sendColorChange basically just sends the string

Comment: And what has that example to do with JavaScript? It would be easier to help you if you focus your question to what you want to achieve using JavaScript.

Comment: @lilezek It shows the rainbow chase pattern i'm trying to achieve using javascript.

Comment: This code doesn't display any graphic or color any pixels, it generates a bunch of urls.  In that context, what is it you need to do?

Comment: @James i updated the question, hopefully it made it a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but would still like to answer.

If you can use HSL values, you can simply set your S(aturation) and L(ight) to a value you like and increment your H(ue) value on a loop to create a rainbow chase effect.

I use this setup in a rainbow script for webpages I created, where it would look something like this:

```
for(rainbowelements.length; let i = 0; i++) {
  rainbowelements[i].style.color = 'hsl(' + counter + ', 100%, 70%)';
  counter++
}
```

This means that every run the for loop makes, the counter will go up one, changing the hue slightly. 
As your question isn't the clearest to me, I'm afraid that's as far as I can help. Good luck!